# How can I easily take down the Witch-Bride of Achriman?

Tags: serious-sam-3-bfe

This boss fight involves a telekinetic witch that can teleport in, deal slight damage and freeze you and your aim in place for a few seconds and then teleport out. She's assisted by a great deal of enemies, from hordes of Beheaded Rocketeers to Scrapjack Rocketeers, that can make a great deal of damage during this period.

Since she can teleport pretty much anywhere and lock you in at the most unfortunate of times, this fight needs to be planned very carefully. Supplies scaringly abund, but they don't help with the major challenge - locating and aiming at the witch *before* she attacks: if she surprises me from behind I'll be powerless to do anything about it.

What can I do to make this fight as painless as possible?

Answer (score 3):

The key thing here is the witch needs visual contact to attack you. On the same hand, there is a small container which contains the keys to the next area you have to pick up anyway.

What you should do is rush for the container, pick up the keys and look out while staying inside. She'll have to get out from some place she can attack you, so her possibilities are limited. Once she does, quickly locate her and start shooting her down with whatever weapon — she doesn't have much health, so a couple magazines from your machine gun will do the job pretty easily.

Comment: you don't have to go into a building, I found that backing up against a wall or anything that limits her line of sight to roughly the area of the screen helps immensely. Also, **she won't attack if you are looking (e.g. aiming your gun) right at her**, so I always looked 500-600 pixels away while waiting for her attack animation to start, then began firing.

Comment: @jeff that is correct, when I wrote this answer I thought she was a one-off boss fight, but that's in hindsight obviously not how a serious sam game rolls.